# What does C^0([0,1]) mean?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am confused with what this denote. Does it mean the set of all continuous functions on [0,1]? I also find C([0,1]) in some books. Are they the same thing? Is f_n=n*cos(x) in it?

Comment: Generally $C^k$ means $k$ times continuously differentiable, $k=0$ means just continuous.

Comment: The notation used by [mathworld.wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/C-kFunction.html) agrees with $C^0(X)$ being the function-space of continuous functions over the domain $X$.  At the same time $C^k(X)$ the space of $k$-differentiable functions over $X$.  $C_0(X)$ might be sometimes used for the space of continuous functions who tend towards zero at the extreme points (*i.e. $f(0)=f(1)=1$ in the case of $X=[0,1]$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ in the case of $X=\Bbb R$*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the set of continuous function from $[0,1]$ into $\mathbb{R}$, if nothing else is specified. It would be more nice to write $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$. So yes, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n(x) =  n \cdot \cos(x) \in C([0,1])$

Comment: And n⋅cos(x) is not a polynomial. Is that right? This is a simple question but I have to make sure

Comment: $x \mapsto \cos(x)$ is the cosine function. It's not a poly, since it has not the form $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots + a_n x^n$...

Comment: @Crasiky no, it is not a polynomial, though there is a [formal power-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) representation of it.  (*Polynomials may only have finitely many non-zero terms while formal power series do not have that restriction*)